# Debug/Compile with referenced library Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

This is kind of a noobish question, but I've been having some trouble with Eclipse. I am using htmlunit.jar to build a small test application. I have the .jar added to my build path under libraries, and there are no errors in eclipse when writing code.

However, whenever I try to debug the program, it throws a NoClassDefFoundError, even though I have the library referenced. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Could you post project structure with referenced libs enabled?

Comment: can u please post the stacktrace here? @user1772510

Answer (score 3, accepted):

htmlunit has a lot of dependencies to other librarys that you have to add also to your libs.

My suggestion: Try to use maven or some similar buildsystem to manage dependencies

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem! I was only adding htmlunit.jar, I added all the .jar files and it worked. It says I have to wait 7 minutes before answering the question, but I'll do it :)